# why c accept a string in a int variable

Tags: c

This is my first question here, sorry if I did something wrong.
I have to make a program that identify the classification of a swimmer. The program does this, but when i write a string, it accept like a int variable.
why this happens and how I fix this.
thanks

```
printf("Write the age of the swimmer\n");
scanf("%d", &age);
if(age < 5)
    printf("minimum age is five years old\n");
else if(age >= 5 && age <= 7)
    printf("Category: child A\n");
else if(age >= 8 && age <= 11)
    printf("Category: child B\n");
else if(age >= 12 && age <= 13)
    printf("Category: Juvenile A\n");
else if(age >= 14 && age <= 17)
    printf("Category: Juvenile A\n");
else if(age >= 18)
    printf("Category: Adult\n");
else 
    printf("Write only numbers\n");




system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

Comment: You need to check the result of `scanf` rather than simply ignoring it as you do at present.

Comment: this is not a complete runnable program, and you didn't give an example what happens

Comment: "*why c accept a string in a int variable*" it probably doesn't, but the code just don't care.

Comment: why do people write `if (age < 5)` followed by `else if(age >= 5`

Comment: if you want to move ahead with only integer input then check with ascii values or check out `isdigit()`

Comment: @M.M: the compiler will get rid of the unneeded condition; it serves as self-documentation :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to check the return value of `scanf()`

```
if (scanf("%d", &age) != 1) {
    /* error, age is in an unusable state */
    fprintf(stderr, "error reading an integer.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of int in C is larger than size of a character. `int` can hence accommodate character. In C we have to think from the perspective of memory. So a variable is a memory location. When we define `int a`; and if the size of int in your machine is 4 bytes then 4 bytes of memory is reserved for that. You can save anything in that memory. `int` means 4 bytes that's all. If you store something larger than 4 bytes then that data might get stored as well depending on whether the contiguous location is available (However you will run into problem, that's illegal in C) That's the answer to **Why C accepts a string in an int variable?**.

Now you can impose restrictions to not allow any value which is not acceptable such as checking the return value of scanf as has been pointed out in the other answer.

To conclude `int` or `char` or any datatype for that matter is a memory location and their type is used only for the purpose of reserving a proper size. What data gets stored in it is not monitored or controlled by the variable itself and it is not expected to do that

Comment: I do not think you answer the question. In the OP's case, if the user enters for example `A`, *nothing* is read into the variable `age`.

Comment: The user has stated : "but when i write a string, it accept like a int variable. why this happens and how I fix this" in the question. I think what he means is why string gets stored in an int

Comment: "*but when i write a string, it accept like a int variable*" simply is a misinterpretation what the user observes. The user probably expects the code to block or even break in such a case. Again: For the code shown **nothing** is read into `age`.

Comment: Yes I understand that the op wants the program to break when a string is given as input instead of an integer. That issue has already been addressed in the first answer. I have tried to answer the why part of the question

Answer (score -1):

C `scanf()` doesn't check whether the inputs match the format. You could try reading the input with `fgets()` and then converting the returned string to an integer with `strtol()` like this:

```
char line[256];
long value;

while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL) {
   char *err = NULL;
   value = strtol(line, &err, 10);
   if(err == NULL || !isspace(*err)) {
     printf("Not a long: %s", line);
     continue;
   }
   break;
}
printf("%ld", value);
```

Comment: "*doesn't check the type of the input*" err, what?

Comment: `strtoi()`??? Do you mean `strtol()`?